# Log4j to write alternate log file if working folder crashed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j

I have done `log4j` configuration properly and working fine to write logs from my application, i used `log4j.XML` in spring web application.

But the problem is if the current log file directory  is crashed i need to write logs in some other directory to take logs during that time.

Give me any suggestion to meet above requirements.

Comment: Have a look on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FailoverAppender

Comment: Hi i am using log4j daily rolling appender is it possible to integrate fileover appender to dailyrolling appender